# JQPlot Printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jquery-plugins, jqplot

Does any body have have a simple working example to print the JQPlot graph.

I am struggling a bit with it.

I need to print it in both IE and Chrome and I am even open to using 2 diiferent methods based upon browser detection.

Also I need to print the X & Y axis lables along with the graph.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Ragards

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's working in IE9.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.jqplot._noToImageButton = false;
         -  -   -
```

Answer (score -1):

You can find a lot of examples at [jqPlot Homepage - Examples](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/).

The easiest example I can imagine:
In yout HTML-File have a div like this:

```
<div id="chart1"></div>
```

And in Your JavaScript do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1', [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
});
```

Of course you need to import the library of jqPlot and import it in your html file:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.jqplot.css" />
```